# How to resize chaco plots and remove/hide yaxis

Tags: python, chaco

I am trying to learn some chaco, but am having trouble editing the plots I create. I have made a grid of four plots, two scatter plots and two bar plots. I would like to be able to remove the white space between the plots, and also increase the width of the scattter plots and decrease the width of the bar plots.
Also simple things like changing axis labels do not seem to be well described in the docs, does anyone know where I could see some examples of how to do these things.

My code is below,

```
from chaco.api import ArrayPlotData, Plot, GridPlotContainer                
from enable.component_editor import ComponentEditor
from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance
from traitsui.api import View, Item
import numpy as np
import glob
import pickle




class ArrayPlot(HasTraits):

    plot = Instance(GridPlotContainer)

    traits_view = View(Item('plot', editor = ComponentEditor(), show_label = False),
                       width = 1000, height = 500,
                       resizable = True, title = "Joekulheimar")


    def __init__(self, time, slow, baz, *args, **kw):

        super(ArrayPlot, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        # Create a GridContainer to hold all of our plots: 2 rows, 2 columns
        container = GridPlotContainer(shape=(2,2),
                                      spacing=(10.0,0.0),
                                      valign='top',
                                      bgcolor='white')

        ## plot baz data
        # time series
        plotdata1 = ArrayPlotData(x=time,y=baz)
        plot1 = Plot(plotdata1)
        plot1.plot(("x","y"), type = "scatter", color = "blue", marker='circle')
        plot1.set(width=30.0, height=20.0, resizable='hv')  # does nothing!!!!!!!!!


        # histogram
        hist, bins = np.histogram(baz, bins=30, density=True)
        center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2
        width = center[1]-center[0]
        plotdata2 = ArrayPlotData(x=center, y=hist)
        plot2 = Plot(plotdata2, orientation='v', axis_line_visible=False, resizable = 'hv')
        plot2.plot(("x","y"), type = "bar", color = "blue", bar_width=width,
                   fill_color='green')
        plot2.range2d.y_range.low = 0

        ## plot slow data
        # time series
        plotdata3 = ArrayPlotData(x=time,y=slow)
        plot3 = Plot(plotdata3)
        plot3.plot(("x","y"), type = "scatter", color = "blue", marker='circle')    



        # histogram
        hist, bins = np.histogram(slow, bins=30, density=True)
        center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2
        width = center[1]-center[0]
        plotdata4 = ArrayPlotData(x=center,y=hist)
        plot4 = Plot(plotdata4, orientation='v', axis_line_visible=False, resizable = 'hv')
        xlim=plot4.index_mapper.range
        plot4.plot(("x","y"), type = "bar", color = "blue", bar_width=width,
                   fill_color='green')   
        plot4.range2d.y_range.low = 0


        # Add to the grid container
        container.add(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4)
        self.plot = container




TIME = np.linspace(0, 1000, 1000)
SLOW = np.random.randn(1000)
BAZ = np.random.randn(1000)

grid_plot = ArrayPlot(TIME, SLOW, BAZ)
grid_plot.configure_traits()
```

Comment: Documentation is indeed Chaco's weak spot. I usually try to find what I need in the [annotated examples](http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/user_manual/annotated_examples.html).